# mysql - Apply condition only to sum not entire query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, one for artists and another for their artworks.

When querying all the artists in the system I want to compile a report of their artworks.
Currently, I have this.

```sql
select artists.*,
    sum(case when artworks.status = 'rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedCount,
    sum(case when artworks.status = 'pending' then 1 else 0 end) as pendingCount,
    sum(case when artworks.status = 'verified' then 1 else 0 end) as verifiedCount
from artists,artworks
where artists.id=artworks.artist_id
group by artists.id;
```

This works as intended, but some artists don't have any artwork and as such they are excluded from the result.
What I want is to list all the artists even if they don't have any artwork, zeroing out the counts for them.

Comment: Use explicit join, left join namely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN and Count the NULL

> ```
> CREATE TABLE artists(id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO artists VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE artworks (artist_id int, Status varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO artworks VALUES (1,'rejected'),(2,'pending'),(3,'verified')
> ```

> ```
> select artists.*,
>     sum(case when artworks.status = 'rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedCount,
>     sum(case when artworks.status = 'pending' then 1 else 0 end) as pendingCount,
>     sum(case when artworks.status = 'verified' then 1 else 0 end) as verifiedCount,
>     SUM(CASE WHEN artworks.status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as no_work 
> from artists LEFT JOIN artworks ON  artists.id=artworks.artist_id
> group by artists.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | rejectedCount | pendingCount | verifiedCount | no_work
> -: | ------------: | -----------: | ------------: | ------:
>  1 |             1 |            0 |             0 |       0
>  2 |             0 |            1 |             0 |       0
>  3 |             0 |            0 |             1 |       0
>  4 |             0 |            0 |             0 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48bc97c2e9c4bccc2380acf598acb185)*

Comment: Do I need to count no_work if it is gauranteed by application code that artworks.status will always have a value?

Comment: No you don't need to count it is an example how you can count it and how left join works. If you want to count them and also you have status NULL then check artworks.artist_id  if it is NULL